# When I'm trying to get the count of characters in my string which is "£" with strlen(), why does it return 2?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I want to create inputs in html5 with a maxlength.

I have a text and I have to transform into a form with inputs. The maxlength of inputs are defined into the text. But with the £ characters strlen returns 2.

Does somebody know why please?

```
$strTEST = "£";
$i = strlen($strTEST);
var_dump($i); // display 2
```

Comment: Google: multibyte characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://php.net/strlen

> Note:
>
> strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of
>   characters in a string.

If you go to http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ and search for £:

```
Unicode code point     character    hex      name

U+00A3                 £            c2 a3    POUND SIGN
```

You can see the hex representations needs two bytes to store this specific character.

An alternative solution to circumvent this problem would be using [mb_strlen](http://php.net/mb_strlen)

From: http://php.net/mb_strlen

> Returns the number of characters in string str having character
>   encoding encoding. **A multi-byte character is counted as 1**.

Comment: You can also use [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php#118484) if you want to count the UTF-8 characters